# document.getElementById() returns NULL when called from external JS file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom, document, getelementbyid

I've looked through all the other questions/solutions related to this issue and can't find the solution.

I have a basic aspx page with a button. the OnClick calls a JS function. the Javascript function calls document.getElementById() which works. I then call a sub-function that lives in an external JA file and the same call fails. Why?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="jstest.aspx.cs" Inherits="jstest" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="RunAtStartup" OnClick="function1();" text="Click Me" />
    </div>
    </form>

    <script>
    function function1()
    {
        if (document.getElementById("<%= RunAtStartup.ClientID %>") == null)
            alert('function1 null');
        else
            alert('function1 not null');
        function2();
    }
    </script>
    <script src="./function2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the external javascript file function2.js is

```
    function function2() {
    if (document.getElementById("<%= RunAtStartup.ClientID %>") == null)
        alert('function2 null');
    else
        alert('function2 not null');
}
```

The result of clicking the button will show that function1 is 'not null' and function2 is 'null'.

I've tried passing document in as a parameter, that did not work. I tried to do a function2().bind(document), that did not work. I stepped through the javascript debugger and it looks like the document object in function1 is identical to the document object in function2.

Thanks in advance
Michael

Comment: is the name of your js file function2.js??

Comment: See the answer below. You're essentially mixing server side code `<%= ...%>` in your `.js` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the element, from what I can tell, is created by the ASP.net preprocessor.  Since the JS file isn't parsed in ASP.net, it treats the selector literally, rather than as a real element ID.  Therefore, this script cannot be run from and external JS file.  In the ASP file, it replaces

```
<%= RunAtStartup.ClientID %>
```

with an actual element ID.  The external file is looking for something like this:

```
<span id="<%= RunAtStartup.ClientID %>"></span>
```

Again, it treats the ID as a literal string, as if you ran it on a server without ASP.net installed.  My solution would probably be to store the ID in a variable in the ASP.net file, like this:

```
var id = "<%= RunAtStartup.ClientID %>";
```

Then, the external JS file could use the following:

```
var element = document.getElementByID(id);
```

The external JS file would, of course, have to be included after the variable `id` is created.  Alternatively, an even better solution would be to pass the ID as a function parameter, like this:

```
function function2(id) {
    if (document.getElementById(id) == null)
        alert('function2 null');
    else
        alert('function2 not null');
}
```

The ASP.net file could call the file like this:

```
function2("<%= RunAtStartup.ClientID %>");
```

This allows all ASP.net tags to be parsed server-side before being delivered to the client with the JS code.

Comment: Thanks...that makes perfect sense. ASP won't parse and process the .js files. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @WebDrive Sure, no problem.  Always happy to help!